Is there a way to create async tasks with delay, containing the Strapi object as dependency?
After an endpoint was reached, I want to execute a service after a defined expiration time.
That means that I need to use the Strapi instance.
Is there a way to create like a CRON job maybe, but that runs one time, and with a timing set dynamically from the time the code is reached, with an access to the strapi instance ?
I am using Strapi v4
I tried to use setTimeout() in my services, but it says that strapi is undefined.
// src/api/my-api/services/my-api.js

module.exports = createCoreService(
    'api::my-api.my-api',
    ({ strapi }) => ({
...
    // This service is called by a controller
    async myService() {
        setTimeout(
            async ({ strapi }) => {
                await strapi
                    .service('api::my-api.my-api')
                    .otherService();
            },
            10000, // 10 secs for this exemple
            { strapi }
        );
    }
...
}));


if you want to execute your task after strapi booted, you want to do this in bootstrap of your app.
// src/index.js

module.exports = {
   ....
   bootstrap({ strapi }) {
      setTimeout(async () => {
                await strapi
                    .service('api::my-api.my-api')
                    .otherService();
            },
            10000, // 10 secs for this exemple
        );
   },

hi you gonna need to elaborate a little bit more, just tested code on fresh strapi app and everything works, the only file changed is:
src/index.js
"use strict";

module.exports = {
  /**
   * An asynchronous register function that runs before
   * your application is initialized.
   *
   * This gives you an opportunity to extend code.
   */
  register(/*{ strapi }*/) {},

  /**
   * An asynchronous bootstrap function that runs before
   * your application gets started.
   *
   * This gives you an opportunity to set up your data model,
   * run jobs, or perform some special logic.
   */
  bootstrap({ strapi }) {
    setTimeout(async () => {
      const test = await strapi.db
        .query("plugin::users-permissions.role")
        .findMany();

      console.log({ test });
    }, 10000);
  },
};


proof:

the problem likely isn't a strapi object, but your service that is undefiend
you can check service uid's with yarn strapi services:list
Update 2
trigger from controller:
"use strict";

/**
 * test controller
 */

const { createCoreController } = require("@strapi/strapi").factories;

module.exports = createCoreController("api::test.test", ({ strapi }) => ({
  async find(ctx) {
    setTimeout(async () => {
      await strapi.service("api::test.test").testService();
    }, 10000);

    return "TEST ROUTE HIT";
  },
}));

"use strict";

/**
 * test service
 */

const { createCoreService } = require("@strapi/strapi").factories;

module.exports = createCoreService("api::test.test", ({ strapi }) => ({
  async testService() {
    const test = await strapi.db
      .query("plugin::users-permissions.role")
      .findMany();

    console.log({ test });
  },
}));



I tried to do things like that, but it says that strapi is undefined when the Timeout is reached, like it looses the memory path to the strapi instance.
